# LCD Display pins

Tags: gpio

I have been trying to wire my Robot LCD Keypad shield to my Pi.

I have been able to connect it to the Pi using the pins labeled 1-16, (marked in yellow). However, I have had to run wires from this to my breadboard and then out to the Pi.

I want to be able to connect it directly to the breadboards by using the pins on the back (marked in red), as to be able to clip it into my breadboard.
Are these pins then linked? There are no numbers on them but there are the same amount of pins and the markings look like they are connected. (May be hard to see in the pictures).

If they are , can you tell me which ones are pins 1 -16 (which side is which ) if not , can you tell me what they are used for?

tltr - are the pins marked in yellow linked to those marked in red?

Can somebody please advise. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Now would be a very good time to invest a small amount of money (circa £10 - £20) in a [multimeter](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Multimeters/58277/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=multimeter), which would allow you to test continuity between the pins.

Comment: ive actually trying that now and i dont think they are

Comment: Just a guess but given it is called a shield implies it is for an Arduino not a Pi. This may help https://www.adafruit.com/product/772?gclid=CjwKEAjwgZrJBRDS38GH1Kv_vGYSJAD8j4DfZOzln8q2hHqad_02aplHvXkuujt8cV39SBrG0E64rBoCRbDw_wcB. The link also implies that it has an I2C interface. Can you post a pic of all the pins.

Comment: http://www.shieldlist.org/ should show the pinouts.  It may not work with the Pi because Arduino's are typically 5V and the Pi is 3V3.